# How to get rid of line under Tab in 2.1?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

Is there any way I can remove the small line that appears under tabs for android 2.1?

I have found the solution for for 2.1++ versions but couldn't find anything for android 2.1 or less.

```
//tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false); .
```

Can I remove this line by making tabwidget and an imageview in relative layout such that imageView overlaps this line under the tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only hack which i found is:

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

Hope this helps!!